# How to set cookies in a Jenkins plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to set cookies for my Jenkins parameterized plugin.

For example:

I have one string parameter called `Git_Repo` and everytime I need to copy/paste/manually edit/write the value in the parameter.

How can I set the cookie so that user will get option in the parameter?

I am attaching a screenshot:

[image].

Answer (score 0):

You have many options:

- On **chrome** , You can enable auto-fill settings for forms to save your last entered data at different URLs.
- On **firefox**, cookies are enabled by default.However, You can control the content according to the cache memory allotted for saving forms.
- Using [Autocomplete parameter plugin for Jenkins.](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Auto+Complete+Parameters+Plugin)

Comment: I tried and its not working. Is there any other way?

Comment: Another way is to use **Autocomplete parameter plugin** for Jenkins.

Comment: Thanks a lot but Autocomplete I tried but it will list all the data which i configured in the groovy script but suppose I want anything which is not configured exactly same as mozilla cookies then how can i save it and show if anyone use it